# wrapping a complex mesh around another mesh

Tags: shrinkwrap

So what I basically want to do is this building. I am modelling an asset for my game. It is supposed to be the main attraction in that point so vertex count might not be an issue.

[image: Bergeron Center in York University Canada]

This is my base structure. And I am trying to Wrap it with some thing like the next picture

[image: The Structure]

[image]

Comment: The [tissue](http://www.co-de-it.com/wordpress/code/blender-tissue) addon might be helpful here.

Comment: Thanks Let me try it

Comment: Tissue makes the geometry quite weird.

Comment: The geometry of the illustrated building is irregular-hexagonal / triangulated. Your tile is rectangular. Which one were you after?

Answer (score 0):

I used two curves modifier. One was used to make exterior curve. And then used another curve to wrap around the perimeter. that got me the result I wanted

Comment: Hello, thanks for updating with your answer, could you post a screenshot or a litte more information to describe what you achieved so it could benefit to others aswell ?